# What is the error name of "incorrect" but semantically valid variations of fixed expressions (e.g., “false news” instead of “fake news”)?

Tags: expressions, errors, eggcorn

What is it called when one says "false news" but they mean "fake news" and just didn't notice the difference or didn't realize it mattered? It's like an *eggcorn* but the way it *sounds* is not quite the point here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is a form of misspeaking.

I commend you on identifying and describing this relatively common phenomenon, but until someone comes up with a better word for it, *misspeaking* is probably the best word for it.

By the way, a common occurrence in this regard is when a person mispronounces someone's name, such as saying Jim *Waterton* instead of the correct Jim *Waterston.*

Comment: Provisionally at least, I'm accepting this answer. It's a valid answer after all. Let's hope there will be some more suggestions.